# Can I state that $\Psi (x_1, \dots , x_n,t)= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \psi (x_i,t) $ via superposition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, superposition, linear-systems, algorithms

Given that the hamiltonian $\hat H$ of a system is a linear operator and $\dot \psi (x_i,t)$ does not depend on spatial coordinates $x_1, ..., x_n$ with bases $\hat e_1, ... , \hat e_n$ can I state that $$\Psi (x_1, \dots , x_n,t)= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \psi (x_i,t) $$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^2 = 1 $; which implies the superposition principle? I am developing an **algorithm for solving Schroedinger Equations** and I want to know if my approach, namely solving for each spatial dimension and adding a time-dependent phase, and then combining solutions via the superposition principle is a good approach to the problem.

If yes, are there other conditions that must be satisfied?

$\psi (x_i, t) $ are the wavefunctions corresponding to each spatial dimension (which are as well time dependent) and the system contains one particle in $n$-dimensional space

Comment: Can you explain your notation? I suppose that $\Psi(x_1,\dots,x_n,t)$ is the solution of the time-dependent Schrödinger equation for a system of $n$ particles in one spatial dimension, but what is $\psi(x_i,t)$?

Comment: The wavefunctions corresponding to each spatial dimension (which are as well time dependent)

Comment: So you are considering a system with *one* particle in $n$ dimensions, and not a system of $n$ particles? What does *wavefunction corresponding to each spatial dimension* mean? Did you get this notation from somewhere in particular where we can see what you mean?

Comment: My apologies. The system contains one particle in $n$ dimensions and $\Psi$ is a solution to the time-dependent Schroedinger Equation

Comment: To put ir succinctly: no you can't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

First of all because it doesn't make much sense to talk about the *wave function corresponding to a spatial dimension*.
A wave function $\psi(x_1,\dots,x_n,t)$ gives you the probability amplitude of the system being at the position $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ at the time $t$. It must *by definition* be dependent on all the coordinates necessary to describe the system (which can be spatial coordinates, spin degrees of freedom or whatever).

Even assuming that with $\psi(x_i,t)$ you mean some peculiar wave function which *does* depend on all the spatial coordinates $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, but which is constant with respect to variations of $x_j, j \neq i$, this just doesn't work.

To see this consider the simple example of a free particle in the usual three dimensions. The plane wave solution is, neglecting normalization factors,
$$ \tag 1 \Psi(x_1,x_2,x_3,t) = e^{i(k_1 x_1+k_2 x_2+k_3 x_3)} e^{-i E_k t/\hbar}, $$
where
$$ E_k \equiv \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m} $$
is the energy of the particle with wave vector $\mathbf k$.
You can easily see that **(1)** cannot be decomposed in a sum of functions depending only on a single spatial variable, indipendently from the time dependence factor.

If however you were asking about decomposing the wave function as a **product** of wave functions depending on the single coordinates, than the answer would be **almost**.
It is a general feature that when two degrees of freedom are not interacting, the correspoding *time-independent* wave function can be factored as a product of *time-independent* wave functions each depending on one degree of freedom.
The time-dependence is applied to the whole product though, not to the single factors.
An example of this is again **(1)**, as you can easily verify.

This factorization can be done when the Hamiltonian is a sum of terms each acting on a single coordinate. Something like, in your example,
$$ \tag 2 \mathcal H = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathcal H_i$$
where $\mathcal H$ is the total Hamiltonian and $\mathcal H_i$ are each acting on only $x_i$. Then you can solve each time-independent, one-dimensional Schrödinger equation, i.e. solve for the whole set of eigenfunctions $\psi_i^{(m)}(x_i)$ of the one-dimensional problem with Hamiltonian $\mathcal H_i$:
$$ \tag 3 \mathcal H_i \psi_i^{(m)}(x_i) = E_i^{(m)} \psi_i^{(m)}(x_i), $$
where $m$ labels the various solutions of **(3)**.
Once you've done this for each $i$, you have a *base* of eigenfunctions in which you can decompose the total wave function $\Psi$. Namely, including also the time-dependence, the solution of the time-dependent Schödinger equation of the whole system can be decomposed as
$$ \tag 4 \Psi(x_1,\dots,x_n,t) = \sum_{\{ m_i \}_{i=1,\dots,n}} c(\{m_i \},t) \prod_{k=1}^n \psi_k^{(m_k)}(x_k). $$
Given any initial condition, your problem is reduced to finding the time-dependence of the coefficients $c(\{m_i\}_i,t)$, which represent the probabiliy amplitude of the system being in the state labeled by the set of quantum numbers $\{m_i\}_i$ at the time $t$.
As you can imagine, this is in most cases highly non trivial.

Comment: Your answer was very satisfying but is there a general method to decompose $\Psi$ to such states with or without time-dependency?

Comment: @MaR1oC see the edit

Comment: But mathematics suggest that we can treat $\Psi$ as $\Psi = \sum a_i \psi_i$. So there must be some values of $a_1, ..., a_n$ and in your counterexample $a_{1,2,3}$ such that $a_1 \psi_1 + a_2 \psi_2 + a_3 \psi_3 = \psi_1\psi_2\psi_3$

Comment: Considering your edit that was my initial thought (decomposition of the hamiltonian)

Comment: @MaR1oC 2 comments up: "mathematics suggest" is a little vague isn't it? what calculations exactly do you think suggest that? 1 comment up: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I think his confusion is than in a single hilbert space, any state can be written as a decomposition $\psi =\sum a_i \psi_i$. However now we have a direct product of hilbert spaces, so that $\text{dim}(\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2\otimes\ldots) = \text{dim}\mathcal{H}_1 \cdot \text{dim}\mathcal{H}_2 \ldots$. In other words $\psi = \prod_j \sum_j a_{ij}\psi_i^{(j)}(x_j)$ where $\psi_i^{(j)}(x_j)$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ basis element in the $j^{\text{th}}$ subspace

Comment: @glance: $\hat H = \sum \hat H_i$

Comment: @MaR1oC well *that* makes it very clear