# Understanding the numerical complexity in solving a Schrödinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics

Usually, when I read the numerical complexity of solving a multielectron Schrödinger equation is due to its very big size.

I came across the following explanation:

Say, there are $N$ electrons, and we want to solve it numerically, therefore we discretize (in other words, converting the differential equation to difference equation and the equation is solved at discrete points and no longer continuous) the $3D$ space to $K \times K \times K$ grid. I don’t understand how they arrive at this.

The size of wave function values to store in the grid is given by $K^{3N}$. Which is huge even for $K=2$ and $N=100$. (Source: https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:935561/FULLTEXT01.pdf)

But my thought process goes like this:

If there are 8 grid points, then shouldn’t there be $3N\times 8$ wavefunction values and not $8^N$ as the formula indicates. Am I missing something?

Comment: $3NK^3$ (as in your $3N\times8$) is how costly it would be if the wave function took a grid point as an input and gave the positions of all the electrons as its output. But the positions of the electrons are an input. I think this is the core mistake.

Comment: Yes but the electron positions must be taken from the set of 8 grid points positions right?

Comment: Yes, the electron positions are taken from the set of 8 grid positions. Why do you say "but" there? What part of that appears (to you) to be in conflict with what I say?

Comment: That was a typo. Perhaps $\Psi(1,1)$ should be avoided as this would mean both electron has probability exisiting at same grid point. Your answer is correct and I concur.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ discretized on a grid with $K$ points, you have $K$ possible real values. More formally, this means that the discretized version is $f: \{1,..,K\} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$.

For $f:\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ discretized on a grid with $K^{m}$ points, you have $K^{m}$ possible real values. More formally, this means that the discretized version is $f: \{1,..,K\}\times...\times\{1,..,K\} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$, where the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) is taken $m$ times.

For $f:\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^w$ discretized on a grid with $K^{m}$ points, you have $wK^{m}$ possible real values, because this is just a collection of $w$ functions $\{f_1,...,f_w\}$ of the kind discussed above, namely $f_i:\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ for $i=1,...,w$.

**Answer:** Now, consider the complex function $\psi(\mathbf{x}_1, ..., \mathbf{x}_N)$ in $d$ space dimensions, namely
$\Psi:\mathbb{R}^{dN} \rightarrow  \mathbb{C}$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is analogous to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (algebraically they are not the same thing, but in this context they are, practically speaking, the same space), we are in a case $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^w$ with $n=dN$ and $w=2$. Therefore, the discretized version of the wave function allows you to store $2K^{dN}$ real values.

**Note:** if the wave function can be [factorized](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/167735/226902) as  $\psi(\mathbf{x}_1, ..., \mathbf{x}_N) =\psi_1(\mathbf{x}_1)...\psi_N(\mathbf{x}_N) $, then  the answer is $2NK^d$. If it can be fully factorized as $\psi(\mathbf{x}_1, ..., \mathbf{x}_N) =\psi_1(x_{11})...\psi_{dN}(x_{dN}) $, then you have to store only $2NdK$ real numbers.

**Note:** if the wave function is normalized, then you have $2K^{dN}-1$ independent real values in the general case. Further constraints that may be specific to the problem at hand can also lower the number.

Answer (score 17):

If you have a system with $N=100$ electrons, the wavefunction is a complex function of $3 N$ variables. Three coordinates for each electron. The magnitude squared of the wavefunction then specifies the probability density to find the electrons at the places the current values the variables specify.

So if you have a $K \times K \times K$ space grid you have $(K \times K \times K)^N$ grid points for the domain of the wavefunction. And this is just $K^{3N}$.

By the way: The [Density Functional Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory) avoids this problem as it reformulates the Schrödinger equation in terms of the electron density which is only a function of three variables.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, for the first electron, there are $K \times K \times K$ values and the second $K \times K \times K$ and so on, and in the end it is supposed to be $(K \times K \times K)^N$. But why does it multiply and not additive?

Comment: I think I just had an epiphany that could be more explicitly stated as follows:

Number of grid points in space = $8$

Lets say there are $2$ electrons.

However, $\Psi(r_1,r_2)$ where $r_1 =$ position vector for first electron and $r_2$ for the second electron.

Then the multidimensional wavefunction can have 64 values. 

As, $\Psi(8,8)$ can have unique values at the 8 grid points.

Comment: Am I missing something or is my conclusion correct?

Comment: @JyotishrajThoudam this answer is correct but your example is confusing. I am saying this because you wrote: $\Psi(8,8)$. This looks like 2 electrons in 1D or 1 electron in 2D.

Comment: @Quillo there are two electrons in $3D$ space so each slot of $r_1$ is evaluated at 8 grid points. So I was wondering, we would have to store $\Psi(1,1), \Psi(2,1), \Psi(3,1),…,\Psi(8,8)$ in total we would have 64 psi values. Even for a small 8 grid points. Is this correct? 1,2,3,…,8 meaning the grid points existing in 3D space. 

But one other thing, do we again need to include the $x,y,z$ components for each points $r$ that would shoot up to $8^{3\times 2}$ ? Edited:I think the last question doesn’t make sense as $\Psi(r_1=x,y,z)$ will give only one value. And the question is void I guess.

Comment: Consider function on a 2D grid: $f(x,y)$. If you discretize x-axis with K points and y-axis in L points, the whole x-y plane consistes of $K \times L$ points. You need this to get coverage of the full space. With only $K+L$ points you have only coverage of the axes themselves and not the full space. So you would only capture the function values that are exactly on the axes, i.e. f(x_i,0) and f(0,y_j). This is not sufficient for a nonlinear function such as the wavefunction.

Comment: @JyotishrajThoudam sorry, I do not know, your way of explaining things is quite confusing. Are you considering a (very small) cubic grid of side $K=2$, so that $K^3=8$? Or are you considering a grid of side $K=8$?

Comment: Yes I’m saying if $K = 2$ then there will be $K^3=8$ grid points.

Comment: @JyotishrajThoudam thanks for the clarification. In this case ($K=2, N=2$) your example is correct, you have $64=(2\times 2 \times 2)^2=2^6$ complex numbers.

Comment: @Quillo So, the 64 complex numbers are those wavefunctions which I have given above, isn’t it? $\Psi(1,1),\Psi(1,2),\Psi(1,3),…,\Psi(8,8)$

Comment: Sorry, the summation should be $\sum_{i,j}^8|\Psi(i,j)|^2=1$. And for multielectron, $N$ the summation should read: $\sum_{i_1,i_2,i_3,…,i_{N}}^{K^3}|\Psi(i_1,i_2,i_3,…,i_{N})|^2=1$. In addition, each wavefunction would mean ,lets say $|\Psi(1,1,3,6,1284,..,1)|^2$
= probability of finding electrons one at grid point 1, another also at grid point 1, and another at 3, and so on. Hence the computational complexity, I persume.

Comment: If I have to include Pauli’s exclusion principle, then only two electrons can exist at the same spatial point? This would be wrong. I guess we would need to increase the number of grid points and avoid multiplicities.